# .htaccess redirection of pages to default setting

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect pages like

```
 www.example.com/example
```

To

```
  www.example.com/page.php?page=example
```

Actually it I've a Site with free page creation. Instead of long link like this:

```
  www.example.com/page.php?page=example
```

I want it to be short like this.

```
  www.example.com/example
```

I just want to redirect that links.

The script I'm using is made by my friend.

I don't know about hta more. How can we do this with hta?

Comment: Sorry but this question deserves a down vote. Please show us what you have tried and what exactly you are using. If you want to use hta but do know nothing about it, then read about that. Show us some effort!

Comment: @Amit Thakur Thanks for your reply. Doe that work with directory like this.. www.example.com/blog/example to www.example.com/blog/page.php?page=example ? Thank u very much

Comment: @Vlad L thanks for your comments..

Comment: @Amit Thakur It is not working with the other directory than root. I want to use that .htaccess for files in www.example.com/blog/example  thanks!!

Comment: blog/example ? Is that a directory inside directory? ,

Comment: @Amit Thakur Thanks for reply, No not a directory inside directory.. But if I go to this URL in browser www.example.com/blog/example it should redirect to www.example.com/blog/page.php?page=example

Comment: @JpPrasad Your Orignal Question has been answered. And now you are talking about another issue, Well I dont think I should edit it to solve your new problem. so Please ask a new question

Comment: @Amit Thakur Thanks for reply.  Instead of editing please add in comments Or if you think i should ask a new questions its ok..:(

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule in your htaccess file

```
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ /page.php?page=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

RewriteCond ensures that if the request is already for a **file** or **directory** , Rewrite Rule will be skipped